# JQuery toggle two classes at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/celiostat/NCPv9/

the 2 Jquery plugin enables to change (and set):
- background color of div to gray 
- text color to red.

Problem is I have to exactly point the mouse exactly ON the text so that text changes color too. 
I would like  to change background Div color AND text by clicking  -- anywhere -- in the div

Tried various combination from other post..but nothing worked.

(ideally I would also like to change picture at the same time !)

```
$(".item_unselected").on("click", function() {
$(this).toggleClass("gray_cliked_box");
$(".item_unselected").not(this).removeClass("gray_cliked_box");
});

$(".item_text_in_menubar").on("click", function() {
$(this).toggleClass("blue_cliked_text");
$(".item_text_in_menubar").not(this).removeClass("blue_cliked_text");

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a CSS problem, not a jquery problem. I updated your last CSS selector to:

```
.gray_cliked_box .item_text_in_menubar {  /*for jquery*/
    color: red;
}
```

and the text changes to red when clicked.

The added selector says that children of `.gray_clicked_box` with a class `.item_text_in_menubar` should be `red`. This supercedes other definitions of `.item_text_in_menubar` because it's a more specific selector.

http://jsfiddle.net/NCPv9/4/

Comment: Awesome ! thanks Patrick - by any chance.. would you know how I can swope the background image too ?

Comment: (i've update the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/celiostat/NCPv9/8/). Well say i've got all of those icon duplicates in red, and similarly to  the background and text, I want to swope the icon to red for the clicked box

Answer (score 2):

You're fairly close, but the reason you have to click on the text is because you're only setting the class for the text once you click on it - you never set it from when you click on the div.  Thankfully, you can optimize (and fix) your code by only having one event.  If you click on a div, you simply set both items.

You can do this using the `find` method in jQuery to find the span that you want to modify when clicking on the div.  The updated JS is as follows:

```js
$(".item_unselected").on("click", function () {
    $(".item_unselected").removeClass("gray_cliked_box");
    $(".item_text_in_menubar").removeClass("blue_cliked_text");
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.addClass("gray_cliked_box");
    $this.find(".item_text_in_menubar").addClass("blue_cliked_text"); 
});
```

**Updated Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/NCPv9/3/

What this actually does, is remove the class from all the objects, and then just simply add the classes back to the ones you want.  You also don't have to use `toggleClass`.  You know you're adding it so just use `addClass`.

Comment: thanks Entropic for explanations, i 've seen your answer after the one from Patrick below which worked well too